# flutter showDialog Display encountered a problem

Tags: flutter

```dart
showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        // barrierLabel: 'barrierLabel',
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          );
});
```

On my 8-inch tablet, the content of the view that pops up from this function only displays on the left half. Does anyone know how to center the content on the tablet? Is this a feature of the function? Is there a special setting that can be used to modify this issue?

In a Pad sized device, any pop-up widget in the body of a Scaffold will only be displayed on the left or right half when using 'showDialog' or 'showModalBottomSheet' Unable to center display

Only the components that pop up in the 'showBottomSheet' mode will be displayed in the center I'm confused, why is this?

I want to achieve a reminder box that covers the entire interface, which cannot be effectively displayed on devices of pad size

Comment: By itself, it looks centered. Other factors might be causing it. Can you post an MRE?

Comment: Can you provide more context? It's quite difficult to imagine what we are going to solve.

Comment: In a Pad sized device, any pop-up widget in the body of a Scaffold will only be displayed on the left or right half when using 'showDialog' or 'showModalBottomSheet' Unable to center display

Comment: Only the components that pop up in the 'showBottomSheet' mode will be displayed in the center I'm confused, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDHVs.png)

The display effect is shown in the figure

Comment: Might be the BuildContext declaration in the builder? Try it with context only. So builder: (context) return {code}.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In terms of phone size, it can display well. Only on Pad devices, pop-up content can only occupy half of the screen size

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved

The abnormal display effect only appears on the simulator and is normal on real devices

I'm very sorry, I submitted the issue to overflow without undergoing real machine testing, wasting everyone's time

Comment: If you have resolved the issue mark your answer as the correct one